# How to read and plot two columns and plot them from a data file using python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I was using python 2 but I try to convert to python 3, however I am stuck because
after I read the file using pd.read_csv I got the next error
NameError: name 'luv_OF' is not defined.
in python 2 i read each columns as 
luv_OF=data.ix[:0]

I try to follow the step of but it do not work in Colab Google
https://ourcodingclub.github.io/tutorials/pandas-python-intro/

I appreciated any help

Ver este codigo online
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yHFT3nI3yQpZyvTQYdUrX0qf9dYfXE-x

Data to plot luvlx_OF.tsv
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qMdFS0sFRJEHBIezrkhc5dysulpFS4lI/view?usp=sharing

```
#Subir archivo 
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

import numpy as np
#from numpy import *
import pylab
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
#######a cvs or tvs file() para Python 3
SED_OF = pd.read_csv("luvlx_OF.tsv",sep = '\t')
#####leyendo las columnas con python 2
#tipo_OF=SED_OF[:,3]
#lx_OF=SED_OF[:,2]
#luv_OF=SED_OF[:,1]
#name_OF=SED_OF[:,0]
print(SED_OF.luv)

# Parte 4: De manera automática, se encontran el mejor ajuste a los datos 

# ajustar a los  datos con un polinomio  de grado 1 (lineal)
z1 = np.polyfit(luv_OF,lx_OF, 1)
# construye el polinomio 
p1 = np.poly1d(z1) 

# encontrando el valor de la pendiente y ordenada (coeficientes de linea recta)
print("")
print("")
print("Atención, estos son los resultados")
print("Coeficientes de funcion Lineal a*X +b")
print(z1)

#generando las variables independientes
# la variable va desde 0 hasta 5,  con 100 divisiones
luvx = np.linspace(40, 45, 100)
lx1=luvx
luvxx = np.linspace(42, 45, 100)
lx15=luvx-1.526

#Imprimir y ver los resultados de la estadistica
# Create a data frame containing all the relevant variables
#data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'z5': y})
#model = ols("x ~ z5", data).fit()
#print(model.summary())
results = sm.OLS(p1(luv_OF), luv_OF).fit()
print("Estadistica del Mejor ajuste LINEAL")
print(results.summary())

#plotting Omaira Style for final Source
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.plot(luv_OF, lx_OF,'rD',markersize=14.,markeredgewidth=1,label ="OF")
plt.ylabel(r'y',fontsize = 35)
plt.xlabel(r'x',fontsize = 35)
plt.xticks(size = 30,rotation = 0)
plt.yticks(size = 30,rotation = 0)
plt.legend(['OF'],fontsize=16,numpoints=1)
#########comentarios sobre la grafica
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.annotate('annotate', xy=(41, 44), xytext=(41, 44),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.0005))
########end comentarios
plt.tight_layout(True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the column *luv* is missing. You can check it by doing the follow:

```
print(SED_OF.columns)
```

This will print all the columns of the dataframe *SED_OF*. If that specific column is not there, it might be a problem related to *read_csv*.
Finally, *.ix* is deprecated and you should use *.iloc* to select specific columns.